# How does EventLoop work in netty?

Tags: netty

As far as I am concerned, a `EventLoop` seems like a selector. Each one handle many different channels. If it's right, why Netty should identify of currently executing Thread?

Comment: Can you please reword the question... Its not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   Does an EventLoop contain a selector?
 or every EventLoop share with a Selector?

Comment: Each EventLoop contains a Selector that is NOT shared

Answer (score 0):

Each EventLoop contains one selector. With a selector, we can use one thread instead of multi-thread.

- NioEventLoop have scheduled function.
- SingleThreadEventLoop add a task to current EventLoop.

And then, you can watch the soure code of Netty. Below is hierarchy  of NioEventLoop.

[image]